# Pulling data from log in?

Tags: php, mysql, database, coding-style, helper

ok, i have a php and mysql script that allows you to log in if you have a username / password

once entered correctly it forwards you to the members page. here i would like it to load the persons full name of who as loged in, like it does on this site top right.

here is the code to the members area

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="stephen2_phptest"; // Mysql username
$password="********"; // Mysql password
$db_name="stephen2_phptest"; // Database name
$tbl_name="registers"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:index.php");

$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
}
?>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../php/css/styles.css">
<body>
    <div class="members-screen">
Login Successful</br>
Welcome [persons name to load here]<?php echo $_POST['myusername'] ?> <a href="../php/logout.php"> | Logout</a>
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-btn">
        <a href="">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-btn">
            <a href="">Search</a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-btn">
                <a href="">Messages</a>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-btn">
                    <a href="">Matches</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu-btn">
                        <a href="">My Account</a>
                        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>`
```

any ideas?

Comment: You should avoid using raw SQL statements like that. Use the PDO wrapper instead.

Comment: if you are still stuck mail me the relevant files as it'll be no office tomorrow :), you can get my gmail id from my profile. :)

Answer (score 1):

1) You don't need db connection on members page.

2) Try this on your login.php page(with the changes as per your need i.e: here i used **"users"** as the name of the table.)

3) Add `<?php session_start(); ?>` at the top of login.php page and every other page where you need username to be echoed.

4) Here in my example code,$_SESSION['username'] is what you need to be able echo username at the right side of the page. And since you may need to use it on other pages too using $_SESSION variable would be a better idea than using $_POST var.

```
$sql = "select *,myusername from users where myusername = '$myusername' and mypassword = '$mypassword'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    if($row) 
    {

        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['myusername'];
        $_SESSION['password'] = $row['mypassword'];

    }
```

and echo $_SESSION['username'] where you need it.
His name will be displayed as long as he has not logged out,and also destroy session on logout.php.

Comment: thanks for the reply, this just seams to bring up a lot of warnings once added?

Comment: can i see the code you added, there must be somethng wrong with what you have done, this is tried and tested code.

Comment: do you have skype? we can instant message then?

Answer (score 0):

Assign your login information that you plan on outputting to a Session variable array.